# How to remove a field from json field in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to remove member2 from members. I saw script

```
ctx._source.list_data.removeIf{list_item -> list_item.list_id == remove_id}
```

for a list but in my case it's not working. Is that possible?

```
 "_index": "test",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "5",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "id": "1",
      "description": "desc",
      "name": "ss",
      "members": {
        "member1": {
          "id": "2",
          "role": "owner"
        },
        "member2": {
          "role": "owner",
          "id": "3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the update API:

```
POST test/_update/5
{
  "script": "ctx._source.members.remove('member2')"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

removeIf is for list. Your members2 is of type object so you need to use remove

```
{
  "script":  "if(ctx._source.members.member2.id=='3') 
              ctx._source.members.remove('member2')"  
}
```